# How to use a SearchController.searchBar as a tableview.sectionHeader

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

question one :

when a SearchController.searchBar as a tableview.tableHeaderView, and tableview have backgroundColor

why it has a strange color: [image](https://github.com/CoderYLZhang/Search/blob/master/question%20one.jpg)

question two : 
How to use a SearchController.searchBar as a tableview.sectionHeader

when i try do it, my tableView will be so crazy [image](https://github.com/CoderYLZhang/Search/blob/master/question%20two.gif)

code snippet :

```
- (UISearchController *)searchController{
    if (!_searchController) {

    _searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController: self.resultVC];
    _searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    _searchController.delegate = self;
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
    // 是否添加半透明覆盖
    _searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = YES;
    // 是否隐藏导航栏
    _searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = YES;

    // 可以通过此种方式修改searchBar的背景颜色
    _searchController.searchBar.barTintColor = GL_NAVBAR_COLOR;
    UIImageView *barImageView = [[[_searchController.searchBar.subviews firstObject] subviews] firstObject];
    barImageView.layer.borderColor = GL_NAVBAR_COLOR.CGColor;
    barImageView.layer.borderWidth = 1;


    // 可以通过此种方式可以拿到搜索框，修改搜索框的样式
    UITextField *searchField = [[[_searchController.searchBar.subviews firstObject] subviews] lastObject];
    searchField.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    searchField.placeholder = @"请输入搜索内容";
    }
    return _searchController;
}


- (void)configureUI{
    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame: self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    [self.view addSubview: self.tableView];
    self.tableView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;

    self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, ScreenWidth, 44);
#if tableHeaderViewSearchBar
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
#endif
}
#if !tableHeaderViewSearchBar
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 50;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.searchController.searchBar;
}
#endif
```

Comment: Please add your code snippet where do you define the searchController and what you do when searchController's search bar become active.

Comment: @amir-khan added images and code

Answer (score 0):

You can place the `UISearchBar` of `UISearchController` in the navigation bar so that it remains fixed at the top.

So, just add below code at the end of configureUI method and remove last 2 lines of code inside the same method.

```
self.searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = NO;
self.searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyleMinimal;

self.navigationItem.titleView = self.searchController.searchBar;

self.definesPresentationContext = YES;
```

Comment: bug i need the animate of hidesNavigationBar,property must be YES

Answer (score 0):

I have a provisional idea:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    self.tableView.frame.origin.y = CGRectGetMaxY(self.searchController.searchBar.frame);
    [self.view addSubview: self.searchController.searchBar];
}
```

To answer question one: you need to set `tableView.backgroundView`

```
UIView *tableBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.tableView.bounds];
tableBackgroundView.backgroundColor = GL_BACKGROUD_COLOR;
self.tableView.backgroundView = tableBackgroundView;
```